# How to add a mouselistener below other things in the JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, mouselistener

If my question sounds stupid, I'm sorry, I'm still new to java. I'm gonna show you this bit of code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2139430787087799923L;

    private TransparentJPanel mousepanel;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        super(title);   
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        mousepanel = new TransparentJPanel();
        mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        setVisible(true);
        add(game);      <-- here I add the game
        add(mousepanel);    <-- here I add the panel with the mouselistener
        game.start();
    }
}
```

the TransparentJPanel class:

```
private class TransparentJPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8855609189172945035L;

    TransparentJPanel() {
        super() ;
        this.setOpaque( false ) ;
        this.setLayout( null ) ;
    }
}
```

when I add the game first, the game shows up and the mouse listener doesn't work, but when I add the jpanel first, the game doesnt show up, but the mouselistener works.
Here's my HandlerClass class:

```
private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered frame at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("Mouse Exited frame at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);

    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed frame at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("Mouse Released at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);

    }

}
```

So, that's my problem.
Please help.

Comment: is `Game` a JPanel class?

Comment: No. Game is a Runnable class with a game loop etc. Here's the full code for Game.java: https://pastebin.com/cpsMSMxY

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which only allows a single component to be displayed at a time in one of the 5 available positions.  Is there any reason why you need to separate panels? Wouldn't the it be more logical to have the game panel act as a `MouseListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple!

instead of creating a panel for the mouse listener, you can add a mouselistener to the game object, namely as follows

```
public Window(int width, int title, String title, Game game) {
    super(title);
    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    setVisible(true);
    add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    game.addMouseListener(handler);     
    game.start();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work. When I launch it, only a grey screen shows up, but the mouselistener works. When I switched them, the game displayed, but the mouselistener worked only for a second at the start, because I saw in console that mouse entered the frame.

Comment: In that case I suggest wrapping the game canvas in a JPanel and add both panels (the game panel and the mouse panel) to the frame.

Comment: what do you mean by wrapping up? can you explain? im kinnda new

Comment: sure, what I meant is to create a new class that extends JPanel and add the game canvas to it in the constructor. Anyway, that doesn't seem to be the problem, you mentioned that a grey screen appears, so how about setting the background of the TransparentJPanel to transparent (alpha 0)? try replacing the `setOpaque(false)` in JTransparentPanel with `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))`;

Comment: did you mean: `private class GamePanel extends JPanel {
  public GamePanel() {
   Game game = new Game();
   this.add(game);
  }
 }` and `panel.add(mousepanel); // note that the element you add at the beginning is the last one to be drawn (on top)
        GamePanel gpanel = new GamePanel();
        panel.add(gpanel);
        
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        game.start();` cause when I launch that my computer opens a lot of windows

Comment: yes, and make it public btw so you can access it from other files. but as I said, probably the problem is with the background of the "transparent" panel

Comment: but I cannot find how to add mouseevents without covering up the rest

Comment: can you post the full code please? (is there a class other than game that is not posted)?

Comment: full window class: https://pastebin.com/M1uSs3bw full game class: https://pastebin.com/rjrnHAHy no more classes

Comment: you're welcome :D
can you mark the answer as the correct one btw?